# When to use the slow Ethereum network?

Tags: transactions, network, peers, networking

The Ethereum network works **very** slowly.

I often am connected to 0 peers.

So what are (GMT) hours when it works the best, for accomplishing a transaction?

Also, which week days it work the best?

Also, will it help to make transactions if I use https://www.myetherwallet.com instead of Ethereum Wallet for Linux?

Comment: What network are you using? ie mainnet or some of the testnet. Since blockchain is kinda of global mainnet is being used 24hs a day, perhaps on Saturday it is at the lowest usage, but that depends if there's an ICO going on.

Comment: @Ismael I am about mainnet

Comment: In any network a higher gas price will make your transactions more likely to be mined. Check https://ethgasstation.info/ for the recommended gas price in mainnet.